# Is there a way to automatically size the row heights of a Table widget based on available space in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-text

I have been trying to create a table in Flutter with the Table widget and have it expand until the bottom of the screen, without having to scroll to view the entire table. However, it seems like the Text widgets force the rows to have a specific height, causing the last rows to overflow.

An interesting side note is that the Expanded widget where the Table lives does not overflow the screen, therefore no error message is shown even though the Table overflows the Expanded widget. Instead, it seems like the Table is overflowing within the Expanded widget.

Example code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter table example',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter table example'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              child: Image.network('https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/minifigs.png'),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                child: Table(
                  columnWidths: {
                    0: FlexColumnWidth(1),
                    1: FlexColumnWidth(2),
                    2: FlexColumnWidth(2),
                  },
                  border: TableBorder(
                      horizontalInside: new BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[300], width: 1)
                  ),
                  defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                  children:
                  List<TableRow>.generate(10, (int i){
                    return TableRow(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              (1990 + i).toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 14,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              'Normal people',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              'Lego people',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ]
                    );
                  }),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the output:

[Screenshot of example app with overflowing table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeqOm.png)

Comment: What is the expected behaviour? What effect are you trying to achieve? Would you like to make them scroll or something else?

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question accordingly. I would like to view the entire table without having to scroll.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's something most people would want to do. The reason is that if someone used your app on a device with a relatively small screen, the content would either be too small or might overflow. You might end up giving readability, especially if the list of years is long :/

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. In my case I know that the table will only possibly overflow by 1 or 2 rows and therefore I'd prefer to make the table smaller, rather than having to scroll to view the remaining couple of rows. Of course I guess this too can be solved with some manual formatting, but I was looking for a more elegant method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter table example',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter table example'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap:true,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                child:
                    Image.network('https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/minifigs.png'),
              ),
                 Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                  child: Table(
                    columnWidths: {
                      0: FlexColumnWidth(1),
                      1: FlexColumnWidth(2),
                      2: FlexColumnWidth(2),
                    },
                    border: TableBorder(
                        horizontalInside:
                            new BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[300], width: 1)),
                    defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                    children: List<TableRow>.generate(20, (int i) {
                      return TableRow(children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Text(
                            (1990 + i).toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 14,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Text(
                            'Normal people',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Text(
                            'Lego people',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]);
                    }),
                  ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned in my last edit, I would like to view the entire table without having to scroll.

Comment: Edited the code for the whole screen to be scrollable now

Comment: Although this is not the behavior I was looking for, I've selected it as the answer since it is still the best solution so far.